# Textures don’t render like in viewport renderer

Tags: rendering, displacement, procedural

My images just don’t want to render like I see it in the viewport.

As far as I know I didn’t modify anything about the render options, and I’ve noticed somethings strange. I use the separate XYZ node with a generated input, and when I click to view it in the viewport render everything is fine, but when I render it out it completely changes to something weird.

I use displacement on my object the subdivs are exactly the same in the viewport as in the render.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which nodes? Nobody can see them but you. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We have no way to guess know how you set up your project or your textures or compositing settings.

Comment: Attached the node setup. I didn't include as I've boiled down the issue to 2 nodes, which I mention in my comment and including the whole node spaghetti, I didn't see efficient. Anyway I've solved the issue myself, I needed to use the object input texture coordinate on the separate XYZ node setup, instead of the generated texture coordinate.

Comment: If you found a solution, please write it on the answers section so that other users with a similar question can learn from your experience. Read:

[Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)